# Does synchronized lock a Result Set object?

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, resultset

I'm trying to multi thread a Result Set. I want to make sure whenever I call the `next()` within one of the many threads, all other threads are locked out. This is important , because if many threads call the `next()` method simultaneously, this will result in skipping the rows. Here is what I did

```
public class MainClass {
    private static ResultSet rs;

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        Thread thread1  = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runWhile();
            }});
        Thread thread2  = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runWhile();
            }});

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();

        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static void runWhile () {
        String username = null;
        while ((username = getUsername()) != null) {
            // Use username to complete my logic 
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method locks ResultSet rs until the String username is retrieved. 
     * This prevents skipping the rows 
     * @return
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    private synchronized static String getUsername() throws SQLException {
        if(rs.next()) {
            return  rs.getString(1).trim();
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Is this a correct way of using `synchronized`. Does it lock the `ResutSet` and makes   sure other thread do not interfere ?

Is this a good approach ?

Comment: I would have one thread reading the ResultSet adding tasks to an ExecutorService.

Comment: Thank you. I   had a feeling my approach was wrong. Although it works, it doesn't feel right

Comment: It will work this way. But order is not guaranteed.

Comment: I don't want to draw your attention away from Nathan Hughes's answer, but you should _also_ know that adding `synchronized` to your `getUsername()` method does _not_ prevent other threads from using `rs`.  All it does is ensure that only one thread at a time will be allowed into `getUsername()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JDBC objects shouldn't be shared between threads. That goes for Connections, Statements, and ResultSets. The best case here would be that the JDBC vendor follows the spec and does internal locking so that you can get by with this, in which case all the threads are still trying to acquire the same lock and only one can make progress at a time. This will be slower than using a single thread, because on top of doing the same work to read from the database there is extra overhead from managing all the threading.

(Locking done by the driver could be for the driver's benefit, so the provider doesn't have to deal with bug reports of race conditions caused by users misusing their software. That it does locking doesn't necessarily imply the software should actually be used by multiple threads.)

Multithreading works when threads can make progress concurrently, see [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law). If you have a situation where you can read the ResultSet and use the results to create tasks which you submit to an ExecutorService (as Peter Lawrey recommends in a comment) then that would make more sense (as long as those tasks can work independently and don't have to wait on each other).

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to create the ResultSet, then copy all the data into a DTO (Data Transfer Object) or a DAO (Data Access Object). After having the data on the DTO or DAO, close your ResultSet, Statement and Connection.

A very simple structure to creat a DTO/DAO to store records in order, its fields, and parsing capabilities is this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> table = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
HashMap<String, Object> record = new HashMap<String, Object>();
String field1 = "something";
Integer field2 = new Integer(45);
record.put("field1", field1);
record.put ("field2", field2);
table.add(record);
```

You may (and probably you should) automate and make the DTO/DAO flexible enough to use the same class in any table, without hard code or fixed names.

Remember that you will need to create a wrapper and the methods for storing/reading the data, and that these methods should be thread safe.

Keep in mind that this design only works if you have enough memory to store all the records of your ResultSet.